# How to hide or destroy a popup window when click outside the popup window

Tags: windows, winapi, popup

When click a button , I  create a window with popup style and show it .
And , I want to hide or destroy this window when i click outside the window.
i can do this by using  wm_killfocus message. When the window receive the message ,hide the window .
but the problem is :
 when the window is exist , if i click the button , the window should hide .
but the fact is:
when click the button , the window receive the wm_killfocus message and then the button receive WM_lbuttondown message ,  the window hide when receive wm_killfocus, and the click message event let the window show again. 
So ,the final effect is window don't hide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destroying the window immediately, post a custom window message to yourself via `PostMessage()` instead.  If the button is clicked before the message is received, set a flag somewhere and update the existing window as needed.  When the message handler receives the message, hide/destroy the window only if the flag is not set.